# Delay multiple calls in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm developing an application in Android using retrofit and rxjava. Basically I have a web service(themoviedb) which I connect to download/synchronize data. The issue I'm having is usually I'm getting error 429 too many requests when I'm attempting to download too many episodes data. Every request should be delayed by 500 milliseconds.

My code is :

```
public void downloadSeason(int seasonNumber)
{
    Log.d(TAG,"adding a season"+seasonNumber);
    int delay = 500;
    Observable<SeriesSeasonResponse> seasonSpecs = mSeasonService.getSeasonSpecs(seriesEntity.getId(), seasonNumber,
            Consts.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, Consts.API_KEY_V3);
    seasonSpecs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .delay(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
               .subscribe(new Observer<SeriesSeasonResponse>()
    {

        @Override
        public void onComplete()
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(SeriesSeasonResponse seriesSeasonResponse)
        {
            addSeasonToDataBase(seriesEntity.getName(), seriesSeasonResponse);

            Observable.range(1, seriesSeasonResponse.getEpisodes().size())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"adding season"+seriesSeasonResponse.getSeasonNumber()+" episode"+integer);
                            EpisodeInSeason currentEpisode = seriesSeasonResponse.getEpisodes().get(integer);
                            Observable<EpisodeSpecsResponse> episodeSpecs = mEpisodeSpecsService.getEpisodeSpecs(seriesEntity.getId(), currentEpisode.getSeasonNumber(), currentEpisode.getEpisodeNumber(), Consts.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, Consts.API_KEY_V3);
                            episodeSpecs
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                                .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                    .subscribe(new Observer<EpisodeSpecsResponse>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onNext(EpisodeSpecsResponse episodeSpecsResponse) {

                                            addEpisodeToDataBase(seriesEntity.getId(),episodeSpecsResponse);
                                            Log.d(TAG,String.format("added "+"S%02dE%02d",episodeSpecsResponse.getSeasonNumber(),episodeSpecsResponse.getEpisodeNumber()));
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete() {

                                        }
                                    });

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Episode error= "+e.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {

                        }
                    });

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Season error= "+e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The delay-function adds the given delay to each emitted value. 
So your current implementation will fire all requests as fast as possible and each emitted response will be delayed by 500 ms. This is not what you want to achieve.

Try to add the delay after the line `Observable.range(1, ...)` by using this line of code `.concatMap(i-> Observable.just(i).delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))` and remove all other delays.

If you want to read further information about the concat operator:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html